# TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance. In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, native, enzyme

I'm trying to test a useState value of and object in react native with enzyme and jest.
I got it working when using a state with only one value but i'm failing with many values in useState with above error.
In the onchange i use the spread operator and i think it's this i need to somehow implement in my test under mockEvent, but i can't find a way and i am stuck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Component:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

const RegisterScreen = () => {
const [user, setUser] = React.useState({ name: "", email: "", password: "", password2: "" });
return (
<View testID='register-component'>
  <Text testID='test'>RegisterScreen</Text>
  <TextInput
    testID='register-input-name'
    onChangeText={(e) => {
      setUser(...user, [name], e.target.value);
    }}
    name='name'
    value={user.name}
  />
  <TextInput testID='register-input-email' />
  <TextInput testID='register-input-password' label='Password' autoCapitalize='none' autoCorrect={false} secureTextEntry={true} />
  <TextInput testID='register-input-confirm' />
  <TouchableOpacity testID='register-submit-button' />
</View>
);
};

export default RegisterScreen;
```

Test:

```
test("name input changes state", () => {
    const mockSetUser = jest.fn();
    React.useState = jest.fn(() => [{ name: "", email: "", password: "", password2: "" }, mockSetUser]);

    const wrapper = shallow(<RegisterScreen />);
    const nameinput = wrapper.find("[testID='register-input-name']");

    const mockEvent = { target: { name: "name", value: "test" } };

    nameinput.simulate("changeText", mockEvent);
    const nameVal = nameinput.find("[value='test']");
    expect(nameVal.length).toBe(1);
  });
```

Comment: Try `setUser({ ...user, {name: e.target.value} });`

Comment: @Estus Flask good catch that's it. posted answer

Answer (score 6):

The problem is this:

```
  setUser(...user, [name], e.target.value);
```

which is incorrect for your intent. Replacing with this might solve it.

```
 setUser({ ...user, name: e.target.value })
```

Comment: Great help. Another problem is that i tried to use reactjs in react native.
Correct way to write was: 
    onChangeText={(newName) => setUser({ ...user, name: newName })}


However, the test is still failing and i think it's to do with the syntax in this mockEvent im used to typing for reactjs and now i need to adapt it to react native syntax and im failing miserably.
const mockEvent = { target: { name: "name", value: "test" } };